# Infinite scroll: set scrollTop() such that page does not shift

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am adding a child element to a container with fixed height and overflow:scroll. I want the insides to NOT shift even when the element is added before the first child (like for infinite scroll).

I'm trying to set the scrollTop, but it's not having any effect.

```js
$("#button").on("click", function(){
        var height = $("#parent_insides").height();
        var scroll_y =  $("#parent_insides").offset().top;

        $("#parent_insides").prepend( $("#childpre") );
        var new_height = $("#parent_insides").height(); 
        var new_scroll_y =  scroll_y - (new_height - height);

         $("#parent_insides").scrollTop( new_scroll_y );

    })
```

```css
#parent{
      height:200px;
      overflow:scroll;
    }

    .child1{
      height:300px;
      background:red;
    }

    #childpre{
      height:300px;
      background:blue;
    }

    #button{
        width:200px;
        background:yellow;
        height:40px;
        line-height:40px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "parent">
        <div id = "parent_insides">
            <div class = "child1">
                hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id = "button"> Add element above
    </div>

    <div id = "childpre">
        hello
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem! It's kind of strange for an infinite scroll to prepend the new elements in stead of appending them, but OK, let's have a look.

First off, the

```
 $("#parent_insides").scrollTop( new_scroll_y );
```

will not do anything because `#parent_insides` is not the scrolling div. `#parent` is, so we should do something with this. However, I think I found an easier solution than all the height and position computations... :-)

I've noticed that my browser's default behaviour (I'm using Chrome) is to not shift the insides at all, as long as I'm not on top (which will not happen if people are scrolling down when content is added anyways). So what I've done is a simple work-around, where I've set the default scrollposition of the `#parent` to offset '1', and now, when I click the `ADD it` button, contents do not shift (I remain exactly where I am, but the blue div is added on top):

https://jsfiddle.net/fmsd5b4y/4/

I think this is intended browser behaviour: the contents will shift down if I'm on the absolute top, but if I scrolled down (even just one pixel) I want to stay where I am, therefore, if content gets added, my scroll position should not shift. Haven't tested it in other browsers yet, but I think it's a cool work-around :-)

Comment: I marked it right since this does seem to work although I'm honestly not sure why! Offset and scroll are probably the least intuitive things to me in javascript. By the way, I need prepend because my list is a calendar; there's always something before.